Simplify with a Condition
EDIT1:
(a,p,q,r,s) are constants.
(* AA = -st (a ct - p) + ct ( a st - q);
    BB = -st (a ct - r) + ct ( a st - s);
    CC = (a ct - p)^2 +  ( a st - q)^2;
    DD = (a ct - r)^2 +  ( a st - s)^2; *)

This following is a trig / algebraic equation (6th order?)  st=Sin[t], ct= Cos[t], st/ct=T = Tan[t]  is required to be analytically solved after conversion to Mathematica form.
$$ (AA/BB)^2 - CC/DD =0 $$
is to be expressed in terms of $T$ which to be solved in terms of the other five constants.
$$\left(\frac{q-pT}{s-rT}\right)^2= \frac {(a^2+p^2+q^2 ) \sqrt{1+T^2} /(2a)-(p+q T)}{(a^2+r^2+s^2 ) \sqrt{1+T^2} /(2a)-(r+sT)}$$
How do we solve for $T$ analytically?
Thanks for help.

what should the simplified version look like after using your extra conditions? You could try simplify with side relation, but this did not change the output. i.e. Simplify[e, {1 == ct^2 + st^2}] where e is your last expression you want to simplify. Another option is to try ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"]

another option to try is to just replace $ct$ by $\sqrt{1-st^2}$ in final answer

Thank you. I have hand calculated some part to recast into the above given  form, please see.

Easier would be to use the tangent half-angle substitution with $w=\tan(t/2)$ as the unknown: this gives a sixth-order polynomial for $w$, which can be factored into a quadratic and a quartic polynomial:
Solve[(AA/BB)^2 == CC/DD /. {st -> 2*w/(1+w^2), ct -> (1-w^2)/(1+w^2)},
      w, Quartics -> False]

(* {{w -> (-2 a p + 2 a r - Sqrt[(2 a p - 2 a r)^2 - 4 (a q + q r - a s - p s) (-a q + q r + a s - p s)])/(2 (a q + q r - a s - p s))},
    {w -> (-2 a p + 2 a r + Sqrt[(2 a p - 2 a r)^2 - 4 (a q + q r - a s - p s) (-a q + q r + a s - p s)])/(2 (a q + q r - a s - p s))},
    {w -> Root[-a q + q r - a s + p s + (2 a p + 2 a r - 4 p r + 4 q s) #1 + (-6 q r - 6 p s) #1^2 + (2 a p + 2 a r + 4 p r - 4 q s) #1^3 + (a q + q r + a s + p s) #1^4 &, 1]},
    {w -> Root[-a q + q r - a s + p s + (2 a p + 2 a r - 4 p r + 4 q s) #1 + (-6 q r - 6 p s) #1^2 + (2 a p + 2 a r + 4 p r - 4 q s) #1^3 + (a q + q r + a s + p s) #1^4 &, 2]},
    {w -> Root[-a q + q r - a s + p s + (2 a p + 2 a r - 4 p r + 4 q s) #1 + (-6 q r - 6 p s) #1^2 + (2 a p + 2 a r + 4 p r - 4 q s) #1^3 + (a q + q r + a s + p s) #1^4 &, 3]},
    {w -> Root[-a q + q r - a s + p s + (2 a p + 2 a r - 4 p r + 4 q s) #1 + (-6 q r - 6 p s) #1^2 + (2 a p + 2 a r + 4 p r - 4 q s) #1^3 + (a q + q r + a s + p s) #1^4 &, 4]}} *)

Then you have $T=\tan(t)=\frac{2w}{1-w^2}$.

Just a question - do you know why people refer to this as the Weierstrass substitution? It a) has nothing to do with him and b) it seems this naming has only appeared quite recently. Maybe I'm incorrect on part b) but I had never heard this until the last few years.

@ngc5139 that’s what we call it in the German speaking world. Maybe other cultures call it something else. https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstra%C3%9F-Substitution

I did a little digging on this - it seems to have first been used in the 1960s but didn't have much traction until the 1980s. And it also seems to have nothing to do with Weirstrass at all. I haven't even heard German colleagues of mine use it but they are old like myself so maybe they never grew up with it either.

@ngc5139 that would be an interesting question to ask on the math SE!

@ngc5139 Note [7] on the English Wikipedia suggests that it's a mis-attribution to Weierstraß and seems to have spiraled out from an article by William Eberlein (1966). Fine by me – I'll modify my answer accordingly.

I wouldn't worry about it. Not the first time in mathematics that misattributions have occurred. Seems less common in physics but I can think of some there as well.

@Roman: Unfortunately the  old Version 8 hangs, indefinite wait..
